# Query to find document by matching a value in an object embeded in an array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to query a collection "chat" whose documents have an array field "participants". This  array has always two objects with the properties id and name. I want to find the document that matches the two ids of the embeded objects. For example, I want to find the following document in which the ids are "1" and "2".

```
  //chat 
//find ids 1 and 2. 
//this is the document that I am looking for and should be returned. 
{
   _id : ytyutu876788
     participants : [ {id : 1, name : Murray}, {id : 2, name : Pier} ]
}
//In this document id 1 is present but not together with id 2.
{
   _id : d6t6d6tdt6
     participants : [ {id : 1, name : Murray}, {id : 3, name : Gustav} ]
}
```

The query that I have tried to use so far is the following which returns an empty array even though I am sure that the document that I want to find exists in the collection so I know that it is the query what I am doing wrong:

```
try {
            const userId = req.body.userId
            const friendId = req.body.friendId
            console.log(userId)
            console.log(friendId)
            await client.connect()
            const query = await client.db('instagram_clone').collection('chat').find(
                {"participants.id" : {userId, friendId}}
            ).toArray()
            console.log(query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator like

```
const query = await client.db('instagram_clone')
                            .collection('chat')
                            .find({"participants.id": {$all:[userId, friendId]}})
                            .toArray();
```

Or you may like to use [$and](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#mongodb-query-op.-and) operator like

```
const query = await client.db('instagram_clone')
                            .collection('chat')
                            .find({$and :[{"participants.id": userId}, {"participants.id": friendId}]})
                            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This another query that does the job, in which I used the `$elemmatch` operator.

```
const firstQuery = await client.db('instagram').collection('chat').find({
  participants : {
    $all: [
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: friendId
        }
      }, {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: userId
        }
      }
    ] 
  }
}).toArray();
```